# Node.js Combining 2 arrays into key:value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 2 arrays which are posted to my server.  The length changes, but each array is always the same length as the other.  I'm trying to turn these into key:value pairs, and return these.  However, I'm only getting empty braces... Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    var macr = {}, i, keys = macs, values = rssi;
    for (i = 0; i < macs; i++) {
    macr[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }
    msg.payload = JSON.stringify(macr);
    return msg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the length of the for-loop correctly. Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < macs.length; i++) {
  macr[keys[i]] = values[i];
}
```

Comment: You were also correct, and led me to a 'DOH' moment, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a `for` loop when iterating over an array and opt for `Array.forEach()` instead. It's prone to errors (as you can see you didn't set the length correctly) and it isn't as clear what you're doing.

Instead

```
macs.forEach(function(key, index) {
    macr[key] = values[index];
});
```

Comment: This solved my problem immediately, and is in-line with other advice I have read on this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate:

```
var _ = require('underscore'); // or lodash
...
var macr = _.object(_.zip(keys, values));
```